# Prove Lower integral of dirichlet's function

Tags: calculus

Given dirichlet's function, I claim the lower integral is $0$. Consider the set

$A=\left\{ \int_a^b s_n\mid s_n \text{ is simple function and }s_n\leq f \text{ on }[a,b]\right\}.$

Suppose $0$ is not the lower integral, then there must be some simple function $k$ s.t. $\underline{\int_a^b} k(x)>0.$ I then showed that this must mean that $k(x)>0$ on some interval of $[a,b]$ by examine its aggregate sum. This is where I cannot proceed. What should I do next?

Comment: Your are dealing with the Lebesgue integral. The Riemann integral does not exist.

Comment: I am saying the lower integral.. Sorry Would you mind give some suggestions on how to proceed?